# jquery change div background image click

Tags: jquery

Hi i don't know how to change a div background image so here is the how it should work

I have some images with an onclick="change_color()" and some divs also with an onclick="get_color()", what i want is when i click the image i should get the image src and then after i click on the div that div will get the background image from the prev clicked image.

all i've managed to do is to get the image src

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
   e = e || event;
   $.lastClicked = e.target || e.srcElement;
   $.lastClicked2 = e.target || e.srcElement;
  });

function change_color()
{
var lastClickedElement = $.lastClicked;
lastClickedElement.getAttribute('data-color');
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the inline javascript, and add a class to the div's and images instead. I'll use `.change_color` for the divs, `.lastimage` for the images :

```
var bgImage = null;

$('img.lastimage').on('click', function() {
    bgImage = this.src;
});

$('div.change_color').on('click', function() {
    if (bgImage) $(this).css('background-image','url('+bgImage+')')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vkJ3n/)

Comment: thank you so much i don't know why i've complicated my code so much... again thank you!

Comment: You are again asking when I'm asking and not let me get 1k reputation :P :(

Comment: @WooCaSh - Sorry, I'll upvote your answer at least? There you go 1K!

Comment: @adeneo Look on my profile description and `Successes on Stack Overflow:` sextion :)

Comment: @adeneo `-80` reversal Serial upvoting reversed :/

Answer (score 1):

Try something this:

```
$(function(){
    var lastSrc = '';    

    $('img').on('click', function(){
        lastSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    });

    $('div').on('click', function(){
        $(this).css('background-image','url('+ lastSrc +')')
    });
});
```